# How to get tree combinations in mongo using mapreduce

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I'm storing the tree-like data in this format.

```
{
    "_id" : 1,

}
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "parent" : 1
}

{
    "_id" : 3,
    "parent" : 2
}

{
    "_id" : 4,
    "parent" : 2
}
```

I want to print the combinations from root node to leaf node with map reduce. Like a tree-preorder traversal

Output:

```
1,2
1,2,3
1,2,4
```

How can I do this? I've learnt map reduce but couldn't write for this.

Comment: explain your output specification? what is `1,2`,`1,2,3` and `1,2,4` ?

Comment: It is  like pre-order traversal in tree. Combinations possible from root to child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this query cover depth of three from leaf to root 
if you need more then there will be another $lookup needed to get full chain

```
db.anil.aggregate([{
            $lookup : {
                from : "anil",
                localField : "parent",
                foreignField : "_id",
                as : "items"
            }
        }, {
            $unwind : "$items"
        }, {
            $project : {
                _id : 0,
                a : "$items.parent",
                b : "$items._id",
                c : "$_id"
            }
        }
    ])
```

> output

{
    "b" : 1.0,
    "c" : 2.0
}

{
    "a" : 1.0,
    "b" : 2.0,
    "c" : 3.0
}

{
    "a" : 1.0,
    "b" : 2.0,
    "c" : 4.0
}

---

as per comment please see deeper structure

```
//db.anil.insert([{    "_id" : 5,    "parent" : 4},{    "_id" : 6,    "parent" : 5},{    "_id" : 7,    "parent" : 6}])
//db.anil.insert([{    "_id" : 8,    "parent" : 7},{    "_id" : 9,    "parent" : 8},{    "_id" : 10,    "parent" : 9}])


db.anil.aggregate([
{$lookup:{     from: "anil",        localField: "parent",        foreignField: "_id",        as: "items"}},
{$unwind:"$items"},
{$lookup:{     from: "anil",        localField: "items.parent",        foreignField: "_id",        as: "fourth"}},
{$unwind:"$fourth"},
{$project:{_id:0, a:"$fourth.parent", b:"$items.parent" , c:"$items._id", d:"$_id"}}    
])
```

> and output

{
    "b" : 1.0,
    "c" : 2.0,
    "d" : 3.0
}

{
    "b" : 1.0,
    "c" : 2.0,
    "d" : 4.0
}

{
    "a" : 1.0,
    "b" : 2.0,
    "c" : 4.0,
    "d" : 5.0
}

{
    "a" : 2.0,
    "b" : 4.0,
    "c" : 5.0,
    "d" : 6.0
}

{
    "a" : 4.0,
    "b" : 5.0,
    "c" : 6.0,
    "d" : 7.0
}

{
    "a" : 5.0,
    "b" : 6.0,
    "c" : 7.0,
    "d" : 8.0
}

{
    "a" : 6.0,
    "b" : 7.0,
    "c" : 8.0,
    "d" : 9.0
}

{
    "a" : 7.0,
    "b" : 8.0,
    "c" : 9.0,
    "d" : 10.0
}

Comment: where have you defined in the code to get upto 3 depth?

Comment: @AnilKumar so to be more precise code reads from leaf to root, so in my edit you will find query shows 4 entries and this will give you an idea how to extend it

Comment: thanks for your answer. But how about 'n' is the depth? Do i have to write it n times?

Comment: @AnilKumar in this case - yes, or you can shft you solution to client and write chunk of code in your favourite langugae